# Passing parameters to form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm instantiating a comment-form from the TasksController's show action, but the params are not passed along to the form.

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController

def show
  @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  @comment = Comment.new(task_id: @task.id)
end
```

views/tasks/show.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @comment, html: {class: "centrera_parent"}, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Add a comment", class: "centrera_child" %><br />
<%= f.submit "Post Comment" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your source HTML to better understand what FormHelpers do.

With the `form_for` `f.text_field` will generate names attributes in the format:

```
messages[subject]
```

Consequently, your params will be in the format:

```
params[:messages][:subject]
```

You can also use `<%= debug params %>` to inspect what's in params, it's very helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't understand how to pass something correctly to params from the controller. I'm actually now passing the value, but with the wrong key. My (working) hack now is to use <%= f.hidden_field 'task_id', :value => params[:id] %> in the view.